# Regex to get substring between first and last occurence

Tags: javascript, regex

Assume there is the string

```
just/the/path/to/file.txt
```

I need to get the part between the first and the last slash: `the/path/to`

I came up with this regex: `/^(.*?).([^\/]*)$/`, but this gives me everything in front of the last slash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `[^/]*`, since that won't match anything that contains a slash. Just use `.*` to match anything:

```
/(.*?)\/(.*)\/(.*)/
```

Group 1 = `just`, Group 2 = `the/path/to` and Group 3 = `file.txt`.

Comment: Thanks. And if I would like to add the first folder and the filename in a match, too?

Comment: That's everything. Do you mean you want them in separate capture groups?

Comment: Yes. Maybe I need the first folder and the filename for further processing. Althought the main issue here is to get the middle part as you did it.

Comment: I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The regex should be `\/(.*)\/`. You can check my below demo:

```js
const regex = /\/(.*)\//;
const str = `just/the/path/to/file.txt`;
let m;

if ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    console.log(m[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This regex expression will do the trick

```js
const str = "/the/path/to/the/peace";
console.log(str.replace(/[^\/]*\/(.*)\/[^\/]*/, "$1"));
```

`[^\/]*\/(.*)\/[^\/]*`

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in only matching consecutive parts with a single `/` and no `//`

```
^[^/]*\/((?:[^\/]+\/)*[^\/]+)\/[^\/]*$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `[^/]*\/` [Negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated), optionally match any char except `/` and then match the first `/`
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `(?:[^\/]+\/)*` Optionally repeat matching 1+ times any char except `/` followed by matching the `/`
  - `[^\/]+` Match 1+ times any char except `/`
- `)` Close group 1
- `\/[^\/]*` Match the last `/` followed by optionally matching any char except `/`
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HXQNbZ/1/)

```js
const regex = /^[^/]*\/((?:[^\/]+\/)*[^\/]+)\/[^\/]*$/;
[
  "just/the/path/to/file.txt",
  "just/the/path",
  "/just/",
  "just/the/path/to/",
  "just/the//path/test",
  "just//",
].forEach(str => {
  const m = str.match(regex);
  if (m) {
    console.log(m[1])
  };
});
```